# Numpy arrays getting "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" in a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, loops

I am getting his error and cannot work out why. Apparently this code worked in Python 2, I am using Python 3.7 and it seems like that is the issue? Is someone able to explain what is wrong here?

```
A = np.array([[10,12],[12,10]])
b= np.array([2,1])
x0 = np.array([0., 0.])
tol =  10 ** (-15)
max_iter = 20
w = 1.5


def SOR(A, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w): 
    if (w<=1 or w>2): 
        print('w should be inside [1, 2)'); 
        step = -1; 
        x = float('nan') 
        return 
    n = b.shape 
    x = x0 

    for step in range (1, max_iter): 
        for i in range(n[0]): 
            new_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, :i], x[:i])
            old_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, i+1 :], x0[ i+1: ]) 
            x[i] = (b[i] - (old_values_sum + new_values_sum)) / A[i, i] 
            x[i] = np.dot(x[i], w) + np.dot(x0[i], (1 - w))  
        if (np.linalg.norm(x - x0) < tol): 
        if (np.linalg.norm(np.dot(A, x)-b ) < tol):
            print(step) 
            break 
        x0 = x

    print("X = {}".format(x)) 
    print("The number of iterations is: {}".format(step))
    return x
x = SOR(A, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w)
print(np.dot(A, x))
```

I obtained the following error message:

```
Error:  x[i]=(1-w)*x[i]-w*(np.dot(A[i,:],x)-b[i]-A[i,i]*x[i])/A[i,i]  
   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Trying to implement the SOR method with above code, why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect; include your initial debugging trace: what are the offending values at the point of error, and how do they differ from what you need.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: `x/x0` is a (2,) shape array; `x[i]` is the slot for one number.  Apparently in your error line the RHS of the assignment is producing an array with more than one value.  You need to evaluate it by itself and check the value and `shape`, and then figure out why it isn't what you expect.  This is just a basic debugging step - examining the values in the problem line.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have multiple files with similar names or you are in the wrong folder. It seems that you are running the wrong code.

The following line doesn't appear in the code that you shared and you might want to examine what are your `A`, `b` and `x`:

```
x[i]=(1-w)*x[i]-w*(np.dot(A[i,:],x)-b[i]-A[i,i]*x[i])/A[i,i]
```

You should be able to run the following code where I have changed your termination condition because currently the first if statement is not complete:

```
import numpy as np 
import math 

A = np.array([[10,12],[12,10]])
b= np.array([2,1])
x0 = np.array([0., 0.])
tol =  10 ** (-15)
max_iter = 20
w = 1.5


def SOR(A, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w): 
    if (w<=1 or w>2): 
        print('w should be inside [1, 2)'); 
        step = -1; 
        x = float('nan') 
        return 
    n = b.shape 
    x = x0 

    for step in range (1, max_iter): 
        for i in range(n[0]): 
            new_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, :i], x[:i])
            old_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, i+1 :], x0[ i+1: ]) 
            x[i] = (b[i] - (old_values_sum + new_values_sum)) / A[i, i] 
            x[i] = np.dot(x[i], w) + np.dot(x0[i], (1 - w))  
        if (np.linalg.norm(x - x0) < tol) and (np.linalg.norm(np.dot(A, x)-b ) < tol):
            print(step) 
            break 
        x0 = x

    print("X = {}".format(x)) 
    print("The number of iterations is: {}".format(step))
    return x
x = SOR(A, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w)
print(np.dot(A, x))
```

I obtained the following output for both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
X = [ 270.45162499 -324.44194999]
The number of iterations is: 19
[-1.18878715e+03  1.00000000e+00]
```